# html:options collection - No getter method available for property value

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I need to create a drop down menu where I need to display 5 account numbers which comes from data base. What I'm planning to do is, set those 5 account number into a array list and then the list will be saved in a session constant. This constant needs to get from my JSP.

in my action class -

```
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            ArrayList  accts = new ArrayList();
            String acct1 = data.getAccountId1();
            String acct2 = data.getAccountId2();
            accts.add(acct1);
            accts.add(acct2);
            session.setAttribute(
                    WorkConstants.TEST1,   
                    accts);
```

TEST1 is defined as public string as follows :
`public  String TEST1  = "Test1";`

in my jsp I coded like this.

```
<td valign="top">
    1. accounts<span class="bodyCopy"><font color="#ff0000"> * </font></span>:
    <br/>
    <html:select name="MyDataForm" property="accountNumber" 
    styleClass="formContent">
        <html:options collection="<%= WorkConstants.TEST1 %>" 
        property="value" labelProperty="label" styleClass="formContent"/>
    </html:select>
    <br/>
</td>
```

but this doesnt work. **getting error as - No getter method available for property value for bean under name Test1**. Looks like my array values are not getting set into TEST1.
why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `acct1` and `acct2` with Strut's `LabelValueBean`, like this:-

```
ArrayList  accts = new ArrayList();

String acct1 = data.getAccountId1();
String acct2 = data.getAccountId2();

accts.add(new LabelValueBean(acct1, acct1));
accts.add(new LabelValueBean(acct2, acct2));

session.setAttribute(WorkConstants.TEST1,accts);
```